# Cannot access to previous Payload value after a using mergMap

Tags: typescript, react-redux, rxjs, observable, redux-observable

I have the following code:

```
export const googleTagManagerInternalActionsEpic: Epic<RootAction, RootAction, RootState, Services> = (action$, state$) => {

  return action$.pipe(
    mergeMap(action => merge(
      of(action).pipe(
        filter(isActionOf(triggerGTMEvent)),
        tap(({ payload: eventName }) => {
            console.log(eventName);
        }),
        mergeMap(() => loadQuestion()),
        map(questionImport => questionImport.default),
        tap((question) => {
          console.log(question);
          debugger;
        }),
        ignoreElements(),
      ),
    )),
  );

}
```

I need to acces on the second `console.log(...)` to the same value of `eventName` that I have on the first `console.log(...)`. My problem here is the `mergeMap` I have in between (which is preventing the propagation of the payload). I was forced to use that `mergeMap` in order to get some info from `loadQuestion()` call.

Is there anyway for me to get both values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use second argument in mergeMap:

```
...
        tap(({ payload: eventName }) => {
            console.log(eventName);
        }),
        mergeMap(() => loadQuestion(), (eventName, questionImport) => ({
          eventName,
          questionImport
        })),
        map(({ eventName, questionImport }) => ({
          eventName,
          question: questionImport.default
        })),
        tap(({ eventName, question }) => {
          console.log(eventName, question);
          debugger;
        }),
...
```

Comment: I think there is something wrong with that syntax, I'm getting the error: `Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.ts(2695)` on the `eventName` inside the curly braces on the mergeMap.

Comment: Thank you it worked! Now I'm having another problem with your code. Just posted the issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66574004