# Cannot propagate a value after mergeMap with Redux Observable

Tags: typescript, redux, rxjs, observable, redux-observable

I have the very basic code below (totally functional), that you can find here as well:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-mergemap-deprecated?file=index.ts

```
import { merge, of } from "rxjs";
import { mergeMap, map, tap } from "rxjs/operators";

const loadQuestion = () =>
  new Promise(resolve => resolve({
    title: 'How are you?',
    options: [ 'Excellent', 'Good', 'Bad' ],
  }))
;

const action$ = of({
  payload: {
    eventName: 'AskQuestionEvent'
  }
});

action$.pipe(
  mergeMap(action => merge(
    of(action).pipe(
      tap(({ payload: eventName }) => {
        console.log(eventName);
      }),
      map(({ payload: { eventName} }) => eventName),
      mergeMap(() => loadQuestion(), (eventName, questionImport) => ({
        eventName,
        questionImport
      })),
      map(({ eventName, questionImport }) => ({
        eventName,
        question: questionImport
      })),
      tap(({ eventName, question }) => {
        console.log(eventName);
        console.log(question);
      }),
    ),
  )),
).subscribe();
```

It works as expected but my problem is that the inner `mergeMap` seems to be deprecated.

I'm getting the error:

```
@deprecated — resultSelector no longer supported, use inner map instead
```

as you can see on the image below:

[image]

Any idea on how to get rid of that deprecation warning?

If possible, could you please, fork my `StackBlitz` above and apply your approach?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of deprecation warning, you need to stop using `resultSelector` param.

Your code with `resultSelector`:

```js
mergeMap(() => loadQuestion(), (eventName, questionImport) => ({
  eventName,
  questionImport
})),
```

Updated code without: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66574004?file=index.ts)

```js
mergeMap(eventName => from(loadQuestion()).pipe(
  map(questionImport => ({eventName, questionImport}))
)),
```

P.S. - You don't need your second `map` if you just rename your `questionImport` to just `question`: [StackBlitz #2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66574004-b?file=index.ts).